# What could make a win32 service stop?

Tags: windows, services

A service (Python 2.7) on XP which is supposed to never stop, stops for an unkwown reason at midnight every day, so I have to restart it every morning.

The service worked well for a year, but something must have change on the system a few days ago (maybe the Python version or pywin32) and now it stops every night.

The service doesn't freeze, it stop nicely and the event log shows "the service has entered the stop state" (or something like that).

What could make that service stop ?

Comment: Please don't cross post the identical question to more than one Stack Exchange site - http://serverfault.com/questions/331892/what-could-make-a-service-stop-on-win32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wndows Event Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer) can show you important related information such as error logs that culminated into service crash and stops.